# JQuery Datepicker works on dynamic input, but not original input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am just learning javascript and html, so I hope this isn't an easy question. I have found solutions to many of my questions on this site (thanks to the community) but this one is stumping me.

I am trying to create a dynamic table where it adds elements when the last element has been filled. There are two components to each element: the date, and a particular code. You click on the data cell to reveal the inputs, then when you hit enter or click away it hides the inputs. *My problem is with JQuery's datepicker.* See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/VEL7d/

**Problem:** The datepicker does not work properly for the original data cell. The first time you click on the date input, the datepicker shows up but does not disappear when you select a date. Then, the second time you try to select the date input for the first data cell the datepicker does not show up at all.

The datepicker works fine for all dynamically generated content, i.e. all data cells generated using javascript are fine. Interestingly, I am even able to grab the date from the input box that the datepicker was linked to, even though the second time you click on the date it shows the original "Date" string.

*Things I have tried:*

1. Looking on stackoverflow. I see a number of people have had issues with it before, and I have learned a lot. However, I have not come across this issue before. It seems most people have the problem of attaching the datepicker to dynamically created content, but I do not have that issue.
2. I've tried moving the .datepicker around to different areas, including an onload section, but it doesn't change anything. I know it is a little redundant to have the .datepicker function called where it is, but that is really just where it ended up as I am typing up this question.

I am sure there are other issues with my code, but I am sure I can figure them out. This datepicker issue related to the first data cell is just really stumping me. Any help is appreciated.

I was hoping not to have to post the code, since there is a lot and I am not sure where the problem might be. Here is the HTML:

```
        <section id="chartData">

        <table id="cycle_1">
            <tr id="row1">
                <td class="dataEntry" id="cycle_1_day_1" cycle="1" cycleDay="1" colRef="gray" colDef="true">
                    <span id="cycle_1_day_1_dateText" class="dateText">Date</span>
                    <input id="cycle_1_day_1_dateInput" type="text" style="display: none;" class="dateInput" value="Date">
                    <span id="cycle_1_day_1_codeText" class="codeText">New</span>
                    <textarea style="display:none;" class="codeInput" id="cycle_1_day_1_codeInput">New</textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </section>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script>  
$("#chartData").on("click",".dataEntry",function()
{
    var ID=$(this).attr('id');
    document.getElementById(ID+"_codeInput").innerHTML = document.getElementById(ID+"_codeText").innerHTML
    $("#"+ID+"_codeText").hide();
    $("#"+ID+"_codeInput").show();
    $("#"+ID+"_dateText").hide();
    $("#"+ID+"_dateInput").show();
    $("#"+ID+"_dateInput").datepicker();
});

$("#chartData").on("change",".dataEntry",function()
{
    //Set the data block to the value of the input box when the input box loses focus
    var ID=$(this).attr('id');
    var codeInputData=$("#"+ID+"_codeInput").val();
    var dateInputData=$("#"+ID+"_dateInput").val();
    document.getElementById(ID+"_codeText").innerHTML=codeInputData;
    document.getElementById(ID+"_dateText").innerHTML=dateInputData;


    if ($("#"+ID).is(":last-child"))
    {
        //Get the cycle number and day for the selected data cell
        var currentCycle = parseInt($(this).attr("cycle"),10);
        var currentDay = parseInt($(this).attr("cycleDay"),10);
        currentDay = currentDay+1;

        //Set up new dateText box
        var dateTextNode = document.createElement("span");
        dateTextNode.setAttribute("class","dateText");
        dateTextNode.setAttribute("id","cycle_"+currentCycle.toString()+"_day_"+currentDay.toString()+"_dateText");

        //Set up new dateInput box
        var dateInputNode = document.createElement("input");
        dateInputNode.setAttribute("id","cycle_"+currentCycle.toString()+"_day_"+currentDay.toString()+"_dateInput");
        dateInputNode.setAttribute("type","text");
        dateInputNode.setAttribute("style","display:none;");
        dateInputNode.setAttribute("class","dateInput");
        dateInputNode.setAttribute("value","Date")

        //Set up new codeText box
        var codeTextNode = document.createElement("span");
        codeTextNode.setAttribute("class","codeText");
        codeTextNode.setAttribute("id","cycle_"+currentCycle.toString()+"_day_"+currentDay.toString()+"_codeText");

        //Set up the new codeInput box
        var codeInputNode = document.createElement("textarea");
        codeInputNode.setAttribute("style","display:none;");
        codeInputNode.setAttribute("class","codeInput");
        codeInputNode.setAttribute("id","cycle_"+currentCycle.toString()+"_day_"+currentDay.toString()+"_codeInput");

        //Create the new data cell
        var node=document.createElement("td");
        node.setAttribute("class","dataEntry");
        node.setAttribute("id","cycle_"+currentCycle.toString()+"_day_"+currentDay.toString());
        node.setAttribute("cycle",currentCycle.toString());
        node.setAttribute("cycleDay",currentDay.toString());
        node.appendChild(dateTextNode);
        node.appendChild(dateInputNode);
        node.appendChild(codeTextNode);
        node.appendChild(codeInputNode);
        document.getElementById(ID).parentNode.appendChild(node);
        document.getElementById("cycle_"+currentCycle.toString()+"_day_"+currentDay.toString()+"_codeText").innerHTML="New";
        document.getElementById("cycle_"+currentCycle.toString()+"_day_"+currentDay.toString()+"_codeInput").innerHTML="New";
        document.getElementById("cycle_"+currentCycle.toString()+"_day_"+currentDay.toString()+"_dateText").innerHTML="Date";

        if ($("#"+ID).parent().parent().is(":last-child"))
        {

            document.getElementById(ID).parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML += "<br>";

            //Create new table
            currentCycle = currentCycle+1;
            var tableNode = document.createElement("table");
            tableNode.setAttribute("id","cycle_"+currentCycle.toString());

            //Modify the codeTextNode from above for the new table
            dateTextNode.setAttribute("id","cycle_"+currentCycle.toString()+"_day_1_codeText");

            //Modify the codeInputNode from above for the new table
            codeInputNode.setAttribute("id","cycle_"+currentCycle.toString()+"_day_1_codeInput");

            //Create a new data node for the new table
            var node=document.createElement("td");
            node.setAttribute("class","dataEntry");
            node.setAttribute("cycle",currentCycle.toString());
            node.setAttribute("cycleDay","1");
            node.setAttribute("id","cycle_"+currentCycle.toString()+"_day_1");
            node.appendChild(codeInputNode);
            node.appendChild(codeTextNode);

            //Create the new table
            trNode.appendChild(node);
            tableNode.appendChild(trNode);
            document.getElementById(ID).parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(tableNode);
            document.getElementById("cycle_"+currentCycle.toString()+"_day_1_codeText").innerHTML="New";
            document.getElementById("cycle_"+currentCycle.toString()+"_day_1_codeInput").innerHTML="New";
        }

    }
});

// Edit input box click action and enter key
$("#chartData").on({
    mouseup: function() 
    {
        return false;
    },
    keypress: function(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $(".codeInput").hide();
            $(".codeText").show();
            $(".dateInput").hide();
            $(".dateText").show();
            $(this).blur();
        }
    }
},".dateInput, .codeInput");

// Outside click action
$(document).on("mouseup", function()
    {
        $(".codeInput").hide();
        $(".codeText").show();
        $(".dateInput").hide();
        $(".dateText").show();
        $(this).blur();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: **Interesting Update:** Playing around with the HTML in Chrome while the page is live, I deleted the "hasDatepicker" from the class. Since my code reinitializes the datepicker, the "hasDatepicker" class was readded. Surprisingly...it worked somehow. When I edit my code to remove the "hasDatepicker" class and then use .(datepicker), it works the second time I click on the first data cell. The datepicker still doesn't clear in the first cell after I click on a date, but I can hide the datepicker <div> to make it disappear. It's not pretty, but it's functional. Any alternative suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you are binding the datepicker after the new date picker element is created and classed? I've had this problem before, you might need to break out the .datepicker() into a helper function and call it in more than one place.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. I actually call it every time one of the cells is clicked on. When I look at the live html I can see that the "hasDatepicker" class is there, the datepicker just doesn't show up. Oddly, as I stated in my update above, if I simply remove the "hasDatepicker" class when I click away form the cell, the datepicker will display the next time I click on the cell.

Comment: Sorry didn't see that.  You should try breaking up your code and inspect the element with f12 at different stages, it will be obvious when it is a datepicker and when it isn't.  That will help you narrow it down.

Comment: @Seano666 Under my first update, I said that I did that already. It still shows that it is a datepicker according to the class, but the datepicker will not show up when the input is selected. However, if I remove the datepicker and then re-add it, the datepicker will show up. This works when I add&remove the datepicker in my code as well.